# Trying to detect expired short urls, trouble with status_code and response url

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm checking short urls that I find in the content of my client. So far, I used a simple **requests.get(url)** and then process the response url and status code. So far, that got me enough information.

Now, I've encountered expired short urls in the content. When I open the short url manually in the browser, I get

```
https://short.ly/?ref=expired&url=https://short.ly/abcdef
```

Parsing parameters in the response url would make things very simple to code but the result I get using the **requests** library doesn't look like that. Instead, it returns the same url and status code 200, which is the same as any normal page.

Is there a way to get the url I get in the browser with the **requests** library or must I use a library like Selenium? In my overall process, using Selenium seems like an overkill at this point.

Comment: _"When I open the short url manually in the browser"_ As you could guess, without an actual example of such URL it is quite difficult to help you.

Comment: Apologies. Here's one of the urls: https://t.ly/imdm3

Comment: You can use the network inspection tools in your browser to see what exactly is happening. The URL `https://t.ly/imdm3` also finishes with `HTTP 200` and is then redirected using some Javascript code to `https://t.ly/?ref=expired&url=https://t.ly/imdm3`. If you just want to detect an expired URL, you don't need that final URL anyway. You can inspect the initial response and look for text "Link Not Found".

Comment: Also, since a valid short URL (such as `https://t.ly/4WEYb`) actually finishes with a status `HTTP 302`, the sole status code `HTTP 200` can itself be a (somewhat unreliable) indicator that something is wrong with that URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Jeyekomon pointed out that** t.ly return status code 302 if the short link exsists than its redirects you to the long link which will return a new status code.

if the link does not found you will get status code 200 and via multiple redirects you will arrive at the main site of t.ly
The problem is that requests handle redirects automatically so

```
 r=requests.get('https://t.ly/4WEYb')
 
 print(r.status_code)
```

will return the status code for the long link(https://www.google.com/search?q=foo)

But you cant stop this by setting `allow_redirects=False`

```
 def isLinkExsists(url):
     r=requests.get(url,allow_redirects=False)
     if r.status_code==302:
         return True
     elif r.status_code==200:
         return False
     else:
         #Handle t.ly server errors
         return False
```